# Is spondee itself a spondee?

Tags: pronunciation, poetry, word-stress

Are both syllables of "spondee" stressed in English?

(Are there online dictionaries which record secondary stress? I couldn't find any just now...)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the list of entries indexed by [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=spondee&ls=a), the [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=spondee) shows a primary stress on the first syllable of "spondee" and a minor stress on the second syllable (they use a private use area character to represent the primary stress mark; replacing that with a double prime, the AHD transcription is **spŏn″dē′**).

I take the term "minor stress" from Balogné Bérces Katalin's "[The Pronunciation of English](http://mek.oszk.hu/04900/04910/)".

The term "secondary stress", the concept itself, and the transcription of it differs among different linguistic sources. There is a summary of different approaches in the Wikipedia article "[Stress and vowel reduction in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Degrees_of_lexical_stress)". Some linguists, such as John Wells, would say that the second syllable of "spondee" is unstressed, but contains (or potentially contains) a "strong" vowel (see the blog post "[strong and weak](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/03/strong-and-weak.html)", 2011), in contrast to a word like *pretty* where the final vowel is "weak" (as shown by the preceding /t/'s susceptibility to lenition in American English).

To answer the question in the title, "Is spondee itself a spondee?", I would not describe it that way. (Frankly, I don't think "spondee" is particularly useful in any context when discussing English stress or poetic meter.) To my ears, it makes for a workable rhyme with "blondie", despite the potential slight difference in the pronunciation.